# How do you manage logging performance?

Tags: c++, linux, logging

We have a message processing system where low latency is critical.  Recently, I found that while we keep a high rate through our system we are seeing some "outliers." (Messages that take much longer then they should)  When we removed logging our systems show none of these outliers.

Right now our logging is basically just a wrapped ostream with some logging-level functionality similar to log4j (debug, fatal, debug, etc).

I was wondering, what do others do to manage logging performance, specifically in message processing activities?  How do you manage these I/O bound activities?  Do you stripe it out?  Do you move to databases instead?

Any advice for optimizing logging is appreciated.

Note: I recognize that there might be other problems with our system that causes the outliers, but for the sake of this question I am only interested in logging optimizations, thanks.

Also: Logging is mandatory for our system.

Comment: If logging is mandatory, is it also mandatory to wait for the log I/O to complete successfully before reporting the operation as successful? If not, then you have a whole lot of buffering options which don't exist if a replay of the log always must match any externally-visible state of the system.

Comment: The system must continue even if I/O failed.  Theoretically it is possible to have the system work correctly and not log it correctly, however, having the logging always occur is a very high priority.

Comment: So the "very high" log accuracy priority is lower than the "critical" low-maximum-latency priority? In which case I'm giving Roddy +1. If they were both critical, then the answer would be different. But bear in mind that in his system, the times when logging fails are when the app or the machine fails catastrophically. If that's not acceptable, you may have to raise the priority of logging accuracy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess it's OS dependent to some extent.

On win32, our logging subsystem simply queues the messages up for a logging thread which handles the disk I/O.

This decouples disk I/O performance from time-critical threads, and gives us good control over exactly how and when the queue gets locked.

Comment: +1: The same that popped up into my mind as I read the original question. But I think this is a solution also for other OSses!

Comment: I'm waiting for the answer to my question before voting on this one: if logging is mandatory, then trusting it to another thread to do "some time later, or perhaps never if we crash first", may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: Also, if max-latency is to be minimised, perhaps the log should be going to a volume which is not used for the main operations. If they're on the same disk platter (or even the same bus if your throughput is high enough), then even with low process priority you might find that a logging operation occasionally delays "real work". I don't know the likelihood of that, since I've never tested it out.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what Roddy said, we also queue the messages in a thread-safe queue, and have a separate lower priority thread which does the actual disk I/O.

In the background thread, we also have a limit on the number of messages which can be written at once (dequeued), so for anything more than that we put the background thread back to sleep.